# empty patterns in bash treated differently?

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a script that unzips all files in current dir as below.
The simple loop expands `*.zip`, and unzips each `f`.

```
for f in *.zip
do 
    unzip -o $f 
done
```

However, when the `*.zip` pattern is empty, i.e. when there is no zip files in current dir, I got an error:

```
unzip:  cannot find or open *.zip, *.zip.zip or *.zip.ZIP.
```

I don't understand why bash handles the pattern differently when it's empty. It seems to me that the pattern `*.zip` is treated as a string literal when empty, and a proper pattern when non-empty.

My question is, how to fix the script so that it handles the empty pattern as well?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type a command with a wildcard pattern that doesn't match anything, bash and similar shells will normally leave the unexpanded wildcard as-is and run the command anyway. It's one of those gotchas that you learn to expect with shell programming.

```
for f in *.zip
do 
    test -f "$f" && unzip -o "$f" 
done
```

This unzips the file only if it actually exists and is a file. It also has the benefit of skipping directories which unexpectedly match the pattern.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is `shopt -s nullglob`. That makes bash expand `*.foo` to nothing if no file is found. That shell option is a bashism, though, so the alternative is to check if the value is actually a file:

```
#!/bin/sh

for f in *.zip; do
    [ -f "$f" ] && unzip -o "$f"
done
```

Comment: If you're trying to be POSIX compatible, you need to use single brackets instead of doubles.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.zip' -execdir unzip -o {} +
```